# Is there a common set of best practices for passing anonymous functions as arguments?

Tags: programming-practices

This is a generic question about using anonymous functions as arguments to other functions. I give an example in Python, but the question is not about Python (and I'm particularly interested in whether answers might be different for functional languages than for other paradigms).

In Python it is common to pass an anonymous function as an argument to another function, for example:

```
sorted(my_data_structure, key=lambda x: x[0].foo)
```

where `lambda x: x[0].foo` is an anonymous function to return the `foo` attribute of the 0th element of each thing in `my_data_structure` (under the assumption that whatever lives in `my_data_structure` will have a 0th item and that 0th item will have a `foo` attribute).

To my mind, in all but the simplest cases, this presents a problem for encapsulation and extensibility: what if `my_data_structure` changes? What if the attribute to sort by becomes `bar` in a later code refactoring? Now you've got to descend into the actual `lambda` to deal with it.

Alternatively, this could have been written as:

```
def my_helper(some_data_thing):
    """My intentions are ____ !
    """
    return some_data_thing[0].foo

#Elsewhere in the code:
sorted(my_data_structure, key=my_helper)
```

While this adds 4 lines of code, it is more readable. You don't have to parse whatever the `lambda` is trying to do at the moment you read about the call to `sorted`. It gives the opportunity for type annotation, documentation, or even unit-testing to occur for the helper function.

If something changes, but you still want the local code around the use of `sorted` to remain the same, this nicely encapsulates that for you away into the helper function. And if more than one place needed to sort, or group, or whatever, by the same key, you get code reuse better than reproducing the `lambda` is many locations.

However, others might also say that you are bending over backwards to give a name, `my_helper`, to a little function that is actually more clear to just see it in code directly.

I can agree with this to an extent, especially when the `lambda` involved is very small, but what if it needs to be a multi-line `lambda` that runs into a lot of indentation issues, or involves a somewhat obfuscated list comprehension or some other device?

My question is: what approaches exist for determining where to draw the line between a useful in-line anonymous function that is "self-contained" enough that it is more effective to write it directly versus an in-line function that is too complex and should be wrapped in a helper function. Are there other considerations I'm not taking into account?

For example: [this post on this issue in JavaScript](http://toddmotto.com/avoiding-anonymous-javascript-functions/) states and affirms many of the concerns I've listed. Is this codified for programming in general? Is it language or paradigm-specific? And what about the other side of the debate?

Comment: one may argue that conceptually, this has been addressed in [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260) If your peers keep complaining about your way of doing things, be it one way or another, you better change to make them feel better

Comment: I worry about that in the case when there is a project leader who has extremely strong feelings about one of the approaches, meanwhile the rest of the team has strong opinions about the opposite approach. Knowing if there was a systematic way to appraise "readability" or "encapsulation" in these cases would be a good way to dissolve opinion-based debates about it.

Comment: discussing concerns like this wouldn't be quite welcome over here, see eg [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: That's why I'm only asking here about the empirical question of whether such practices exist, have been written about before, and can be pointed to neutrally without trying to claim they are right or wrong. I leave the actual human to human explaining out of it since that is not important here.

Comment: `what if my_data_structure changes? What if the attribute to sort by becomes bar in a later code refactoring?` The data structure changing shouldn't stop you from sorting it. If the data structure's elements change that's a breaking API change that breaks other parts of the code too, so you have more to worry about than just updating the lambda.

Comment: But you still need to write your code to be robust against that change. It's also not all that uncommon. A `list` could be replaced by a `tuple` and virtually nothing about the API will change, but perhaps some small lambda that expects a `list` method does change. Do you want to debug that in a nested lambda, or in a helper function with documentation? If it depends on the situation, what are the "it depends" criteria?

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Correct me if I'm wrong but in `key=lambda x: ...`, the `x` is the element of the data structure and thus the particular data structure used doesn't matter as long as it's iterable; the element has already been extracted through the iterator. So, again, the only thing that could break it is a change in the API of the elements, in which case the problem will be obvious. Either way, I don't see the point in documenting the type expectations in the lambda instead of the scope where `data_structure` was introduced.

Comment: @Doval I don't understand. I would argue that all that matters about the `lambda` is what comes after the colon -- the actual expression that will be evaluated and returned. In my case, for example, the lambda assumes each element of `my_data_structure` is itself something that supports item-getting and is non-empty and that the 0th item has a `foo` attribute. In fact, the `foo` attribute might have existed *solely* to support some kind of sort down stream. Either way, if anything about the `foo` API changes, this lambda *might* be the only place the error occurs.

Comment: That is, all things upstream that deal with `my_data_structure` might not have any reason to care about anything about the contents of it. Duck typing might even make it desirable that everything upstream deals with `my_data_structure` in precisely the same way whether item 0 has attr `foo` or `bar` or `baz` or no attrs at all.

Answer (score 2):

You draw the line based on length and repetition.  A lambda is okay if it's short and not repeated.  Once you get into multiple lines, or are repeating it multiple times, you should really give it a name.  If your data structure changes, it's no big deal to change one or two short lambdas, especially in a strong statically typed language.  For some reason, though, lambdas give people a blind spot to repetition.

JavaScript is really the only language I've seen where multi-line anonymous functions are commonly accepted.  I'm not sure what it is about the language that makes it that way.  It may be more a cultural thing.  That doesn't make it a *best* practice, however, just a common one.  Also, the same rules apply about repetition.  More so, since repetition of longer functions is worse.

Comment: JavaScript is by far not the only language. Most language with good support for functional programming are used in that way. Scala is a good example. The problems mentioned by the OP do not even occur here, because it has functions *and* is statically typed so the compiler will complain immediatly if the data structures api changes.

Comment: Actually, @valenterry the actual use case in my team's project is a series of poorly written multi-line anonymous functions in an in-house LiveScript-like functional language that is in some ways very similar to scala (and it has static typing). Even in Haskell you can get really bad multi-line lambdas and though the compiler can easily deal with their type signature, humans reading the code sometimes have no hope.

Comment: Well, sure. Anonymous functions are used because we are too lazy to write an own stragety-pattern-like class for each single anonymous function. But if there are more of them or the same one is used multiple times, one should write it once and use it when needed. I would say even two times writing the same anonymous function already shows that it need to be refactored. The approach to decide is always "what cost less in the long term and when does it have to be finished". Unless its extreme time pressure, refactor instead of doing copy&paste even once. That is how I do it.